# How to send CDATA section in SOAP response on Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, soap, websphere, jax-ws, cdata

I need to send SOAP response with element of type xs:string. This element must contains CDATA section. By default the implementation of JAX-WS on Webphere 8.5.5 escapes special characters like '<' '>' or '&' but customer wants the respone not escaped and wrapped in CDATA.

The object with string element is generated from wsdl by maven using wsimport with annotation:

```
@XmlElement(name = "messageContent", required = true)
protected String messageContent;
```

I can accept request containing CDATA section and everything works fine. In messageContent is content of accepted CDATA, characters are not escaped. But the problem is sending response in this object - the response is everytime escaped and I don't know how to properly add CDATA section.

I have already tried modify response message in SOAPHandler and in LogicalHandler(where payload has type javax.xml.transform.Source). I have replaced the original element by new element with cdata section:

```
Element newEl = document.createElement(origNode.getNodeName());
CDATASection cdata = document.createCDATASection(origNode.getTextContent());
newEl.appendChild(cdata);
origNode.getParentNode().replaceChild(newEl, origNode);
```

And everytime output SOAP message is without CDATA and special characters are escaped.

Is there a way how to really add CDATA section which is present in output soap message? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think from method itself try to return the String XML wrapped in CDATA. e.g. `<sender>John Smith</sender>` should be returned as `<![CDATA[<sender>John Smith</sender>]]>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately setting CDATA directly into the value does not help. Characters < and > are escaped also.